# Foreach - evaluate - modulo problem

Tags: foreach

In this MWE, the `mod` function doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i
    [evaluate=\i as \x using mod(\i,13)] in {0,...,12} {%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1.5*\x,0)},rotate=-\i*15,]
        \filldraw (135:.5)
                arc (135:-135:.5) -- cycle ;
    \end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The comma inside `mod(\i,13)` is a syntax character for the key value list, the first option is `evaluate=\i as \x using mod(\i`, the second option is `13`. The result of the split evaluate expression is the key error in the `\foreach` loop. The split up can be avoided by curly braces:

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i
    [evaluate=\i as \x using {mod(\i,13)}] in {0,...,12} {%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(1.5*\x,0)},rotate=-\i*15,]
        \filldraw (135:.5)
                arc (135:-135:.5) -- cycle ;
    \end{scope}
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]